# How to get a "select" html element by Jsoup?

Tags: java, dom, jsoup

`<section class="my grid">`

How can I use `Jsoup` to optain this element (and all sub elements)?
The following does not work (is empty):

```
Elements ul = doc.getElementsByClass("my grid");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Elements listGrids=new Elements
for(Element section:doc.getElementsByTag("section"))
{
        if(section.absUrl("Class).equals("my grid")
          listGrids.add(section);
}
```

I don't know why your current code doesn't work, but it could be because you have a space in your value

Niko

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just for your information. This could be done even easier. Just like

```
Elements ul = doc.select("section.my.grid");
```

or for iteration as

```
for(Element section : doc.select("section.my.grid")){
    System.out.println(section.text());
}
```

**Explanation**

Esentially you could filter tag based on class by **.** (DOT) selector. Refer [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

For eg - el.class gives all elements with class, e.g. div.masthead selects all div tags with class masthead. So in your case you have two classes "my" and "grid" for section tag. So just filter like

```
Elements ul = doc.select("section.my");

or

Elements ul = doc.select("section.grid")
```

This will give you all section tags with a class attribute of my or grid. But in case if you have multiple combination of "my" class and you want just "my" and "grid" together do nesting.

```
Elements ul = doc.select("section.my.grid");
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes are separated by a space. In your case you add 2 classes to your section ("my" and "grid").

If you want to have a readable class, use a "-" to separate them.